# Return Button - unreachable

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I want to create a button, which closes the current activity. Like a "return" button.
Here are code fragments I tried:

Here is the full .java:

```
public class OtherApps extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_apps);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.otherappsmenu, menu);
        return true; 
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {  
        case R.id.previous:
            finish();
            break;
        case R.id.home:
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Activitys are not closed!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            this.startActivity(intent);
            break;
        case R.id.exit:
            finish();
            System.exit(0);
        case R.id.help:
            String url = "http://www.google.de/";
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return true;

        final Button OtherApps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);
        OtherApps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

But Eclipse says "the first line is unreachable".
Does anyone know what's the error?

Thanks for help!

Comment: "the first line" - which line exactly?

Comment: *Which* code is unreachable?

Comment: The first line of each code. "Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);" and "  final Button OtherApps = (Button)findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);"

Comment: You're trying to add the `previousButton` handler at the bottom of the `onOptionsItemSelected` AFTER your `switch` block and a `return`. Try moving it to the `onCreate` method.

Comment: See my comment below: you have two `return`'s that makes the code for button unreachable.

Comment: @YouDeveloper I've fixed the code indentation for you. The problem should be obvious now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work (the first example should be preferred).

The error you are getting sounds as if you have a `return`-statement anywhere inside that method BEFORE you have the pasted code. Search for that, it should fix the error.

EDIT:

```
public class OtherApps extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.other_apps);

        final Button OtherApps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.previousbutton);
        OtherApps.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Do you mean return true; ? I've got 3 of them.

Comment: As Deanna commented, please post the code before those lines. The problem will be in one of those `return true`s!

Comment: I can't answer my own question but here is the code on Google Docs:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1GhDZQBze0NnktYz4DmdtPaPDCLS3PKdkaFkzngT_v_E/edit?pli=1

Comment: @YouDeveloper You can edit your post to add it. Answers should only be posted for answers. (StackOverflow is a Q&A site, NOT a forum)

Comment: Okay, the .java is in my first post.

Comment: After the `switch`-statement you have a `return true`, as a result your method `onOptionsItemSelected` will be exited there. So the code below will never be executed. Remove that `return true`, then it should work.

Though you should define `onClickListeners` in your `onCreate`-method!

Comment: I edited my answer. This is how you really should add Listeners.

Answer (score 2):

If your "first line" is unreachable, then it's more important to know, what the code before these two versions is. It might be, that you have a `return` statement there or a condition that is always `false`.

In this case the code for attaching the on-click listeners will never be reached.

**p.s.**

You have two lines wehre you return from the method what means that the following code is never executed:

```
switch(item.getItemId()) {  
   ...
   default: // here, return if none of the values above matched
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item); 
}
return true; // here, return always

// conclusion: this gets never executed: Eclipse says "line not reachable"
final Button OtherApps = (Button ...
```